# Jtable highlighting with defaultablecellrenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a java program that adds rows into a jtable. When I add a row, it does price check for that row and if it is greater than 100, it highlights green immediately after it has been added. This is currently my code, and all it does is highlight everything green. What's my problem?

```
class YourTableCellRenderer
    extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Component c = 
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

if (row == table.getRowCount()-1) {
            c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    return c;
}
}

model.addRow(new Object[] {"col1", "col2"});

if(price>100)
{
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new YourTableCellRenderer());
}
```

Comment: When setting the background color, it's important to ensure that the render is opaque, but don't forget to reset the state if the condition is not meet. If this doesn't work, consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I could modify it? The problem with trying to reset when not meeting the condition is that I don't want to lose the highlights on previously added rows that meet the condition

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the check in the YourTableCellRenderer itself. The render is called after the data model returns a value. All this takes place when the component is being painted, so I don't know where in the process this code is:

```
if(price>100)
{
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new YourTableCellRenderer());
}
```

But once the renderer is set for the table that's it - the redering doesn't happen when the data model is updated (I assume that's what the code does). It happens when the screen gets painted in response to an event (like focus gained or repaint() programmatically called).